# How to create a vertical button in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I'd like to create a button that is basically a rotated 90's so that it is in effect a vertically aligned button.  So that the the text is like that of a book spine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the rotation property of the button... so the mxml would be something like:

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" label="CLICK ME"  rotation="90" />
```

Edit

As a side note you will probably need to embed the font you are using if you want the text to be visible after the component has been rotated

Comment: If you target Flash Player 10, you don't have to embed the font.

Comment: Really thats good news...I hate that rotated text disappears!